Block signin access based on custom attribute value
I'm have a B2C used to store users for multiple app tenants. In order to specify the tenant a user has access to, I've added a custom attribute tenant (available via extension_tenant claim) which is actually a comma separated list of tenants, eg: tenant_1,tenant_2.
For each tenant I have added a custom policy (ex: B2C_1A_SIGNIN_TENANT_1) to which the user is redirected in order to signin. The policy contains a claim about expected tenant.
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ClaimsTransformation-AssertAppTenantValidated">
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ExpectedTenant" DefaultValue="tenant_1" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
        </InputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>

The full TechnicalProfile ClaimsTransformation-AssertAppTenantValidated

transforms the user tenant list from string to string collection,
check if expected tenant is in the collection
asserts the presence to return error (not sure it's correct)

    <TechnicalProfile Id="ClaimsTransformation-AssertAppTenantValidated">
        <DisplayName>Assert App Tenant Claims Transformation</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ExpectedTenant" DefaultValue="tenant-to-be-allowed" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_tenant" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ConvertAppTenantListToStringCollection" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="HasRequiredAppTenant" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAppTenantValidated" />
        </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>

And here are my claim transformations.
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="ConvertAppTenantListToStringCollection" TransformationMethod="StringSplit">
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_tenant" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
            <InputParameter DataType="string" Id="delimiter" Value="," />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserTenantList" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>

    <ClaimsTransformation Id="HasRequiredAppTenant" TransformationMethod="StringCollectionContainsClaim">
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserTenantList" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ExpectedTenant" TransformationClaimType="item" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
            <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isValidAppTenant" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>

    <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertAppTenantValidated" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isValidAppTenant" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
            <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
        </InputParameters>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
</ClaimsTransformations>

For the local signin, I modified the SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email technical profile. Probably a bad idea, but didn't got it working other way.
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        ...
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-AssertAppTenantValidated" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>

Everything works, even though the solution is not perfect.
Now I'm adding for these tenants, federated login via an Identity provider. I took the social starter template, but not sure where and how to add the restriction. My last attempt was to add a new orchestration step but it's not working.
<OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-check-tenant" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-check-tenant" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-check-tenant">
    <DisplayName>Check tenant</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-AssertAppTenantValidated" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>

Here's the technical profile for the AD Signin
<TechnicalProfile Id="AzureADProfile_issueAADtoken">
    <DisplayName>Tenant SSO</DisplayName>
    <Description>Tenant SSO login</Description>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="issuer">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/v2.0</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item> <!--TODO: check-->
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Item>
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid user.read profile email</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
        <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <!-- TODO update StorageRefenceId to match your configuration-->
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TenantApplicationKey"/>
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <!--<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />-->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="familyName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AzureAD" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
</TechnicalProfile>

It's best to show the error on the login page, but it's also ok to display an error message on a separate page like how it was done in this answer: Azure B2C custom policy do not allow signup on the social signin
Update 2024-06-21:
Based on the log, it appears that the technical profile SelfAsserted-check-tenant was not executed because the IsSelfAssertedEmpty predicate returned True. This indicates that the self-asserted step was considered empty, and as a result, the orchestration engine did not proceed with executing the SelfAsserted-check-tenant technical profile. From what I understood, it is skipped as there were no claims received from the user.

"federated login via an Identity provider." Is this IDP an Entra ID tenant or multi Entra ID tenant?

Currently it's an Entra ID tenant. I also added the technical profile for it.

If you are happy to allow multi-tenant, you can restrict access based on the tenant by populating the ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes attribute.
Note this uses tenant ID and not tenant name.
